# Прилагательное в творительном падеже

Tags: синтаксис, прилагательные

Постоянно вижу такие предложения:

*Держать проход **открытым**.

Сделать доступ **бесплатным**.

Сделать человека **злым.***

Какова тут синтаксическая функция прилагательного в творительном падеже (*открытым, бесплатным, злым*)?
Оно не согласовано с предшествующим существительным в падеже и, кроме того, синтаксически вроде бы все-таки от глагола зависит, глагол распространяет.
Что это за член предложения?

Answer (score 1):

Это *неполные* предложения, в которых прилагательное (могло быть и существительное) входит в глагольную конструкцию, действие которой направлено на существительное (прямое дополнение). Если изменить форму глагола и порядок слов, можно построить *законченное* предложение, в котором прилагательное станет *частью* составного именного *сказуемого*:

Без подлежащего:

> Проход держали открытым. Доступ сделали бесплатным. Человека сделали
>   злым.

С подлежащим:

> Проход оставался открытым. Доступ стал бесплатным. Человек оказался
>   злым.

При инфинитивной форме глагола (в более сложном предложении она может входить в глагольную конструкцию с зависимым инфинитивом) вариант падежа прилагательного только один (творительный), по подобию сочетания с глаголом "быть" (каким). При трансформациях (как выше) падеж может сохраняться, а может и изменяться ("человек стал злой" и т. п.).

Comment: Иными словами,  конструкция инфинитив + прилагательное в творительном падеже = синтаксически цельное сказуемое?

Comment: Да: при отбрасывании прилагательного смысл глагола здесь изменяется или теряется вовсе.

Comment: Эти примеры (проход держали открытым, человека сделали злым) - это, как по мне, не безличные, а неопределенно-личные полные предложения. Полные односоставные. Конструкция со сказуемым-инфинитивом (держать проход открытым) - инфинитивное полное предложение. Полное односоставное.

Comment: Изменил, чтобы отвлечься от наименований :)

Answer (score 0):

**Держать проход открытым. Держать дверь открытой.**

**Открытым/открытой**  ―  **дуплексив**, то есть член предложения с двунаправленными связями.

1) Дуплексив входит в состав именного сказуемого **держать открытым/открытой**  (держать ― знаменательная связка, это обычно глаголы движения и положения). Глагольная связка задает существительному Т.п.

2) Также дуплексив является определением по отношению к дополнению проход/дверь, согласование **в роде и числе**, но не в падеже.